# Remove Image in excel header after exporting the gidview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Kindly help me on how to remove image in my excel header. I generate the excel using export command using gridview as source data

here is my code

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & strFilename & ".xls")
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"


        Dim sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim htw As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)


        grvData.AllowPaging = False
        grvData.AllowSorting = False
        PopulateGrid()

        grvData.RenderControl(htw)
        Response.Write(sw.ToString)
        Response.End()
```

Everything was set -except that one my header had a blank header name because of the image that was now shown -  the image is came from gridview (I'm using arrow for asc and desc) - sorry i cant post any image here now

Comment: It is not clear (for me) what you want. Do you want to show the image in excel or do you want to hide it? You know that you aren't really generating an excel-file but simply HTML with  xls extension what excel might handle correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Give this ClearControls method a shot. It should remove any controls from the Grid before exporting:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";

    System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

    this.ClearControls(DataGrid1);
    DataGrid1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);

    DataGrid1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    DataGrid1.Style.Clear();

    Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}

private void ClearControls(Control control)
{
    for (int i = control.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ClearControls(control.Controls[i]);
    }

    if (!(control is TableCell))
    {
        if (control.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedItem") != null)
        {
            LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl();
            control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal);

            try
            { 
                literal.Text = (string)control.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedItem").GetValue(control, null); 
            }
            catch
            { 
                //do nothing 
            }
            finally
            { 
                control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (control.GetType().GetProperty("Text") != null)
            {
                LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl();
                control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal);
                literal.Text = (string)control.GetType().GetProperty("Text").GetValue(control, null);
                control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```